# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using useRef, and accessing its child elements.

And I am getting this error.

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type '{}'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type '{}'

The code is

```
const subCnt = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();

useEffect(()=>{

    if (!(subCnt.current?.children?.length! > 0)) return

    let lastChild: ReactNode = subCnt.current?.children;
    lastChild = lastChild[lastChild?.length - 1]; //Getting the error here
    ...
})
```

The Line I am getting the error is at `lastChild = lastChild[lastChild?.length - 1];`

Why is it showing this error?

Comment: its telling you for a missing null check, put one if null check and this should go away

Comment: @vaira I have tried that. `lastChild![lastChild!?.length! - 1]` or even `lastChild ? lastChild[lastChild?.length - 1] : undefined` It still doesn't work.

Comment: if(lastChind) {lastChild = lastChild[lastChild?.length - 1];}

Comment: @vaira That doesn't fix it, It still shows the error.

Comment: Sorry read the problem statement wrong

Comment: instead of ReactNode use type HTMLCollection

Comment: let lastChild: ReactNode = subCnt.current?.children;
    lastChild = lastChild[lastChild?.length - 1]

Either LastChild is reactNode or its ReachNode[], but it cant be both like you have declared.

Comment: Don't know much of React, but ReactNode is defined as Iterable<ReactNode>, that's probably why it doesn't even complain that you have `lastChild` typed as `ReactNode` and not `HTMLCollection`. But you can't do `[index]` on `Iterable`. That's the source of your error. You could do `Array.from(lastChild)` first and do the `[]` on it instead. But I think just using two variables instead of one and using `HTMLCollection` instead of ReactNode would be better.

Comment: Instead of setting the type explicitly of your `lastChild` variable, why don't you let TS infer it? `let lastChild = subCnt.current?.children`. Doing it this way, the type of `lastChild` would be `HTMLCollection`, which is actually more correct than `ReactNode` in this case. And then instead of reassigning `lastChild`, why don't you declare a new variable (because its type will be different) for `lastChild[lastChild.length - 1]`? Something like this: `const child = lastChild[lastChild.length - 1];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual mistake is on the line before:

> ```
> let lastChild: ReactNode = subCnt.current?.children;
> ```

I don't know why TypeScript doesn't complain, apparently the types are weirdly compatible, but they really ought not. The type of [`.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) is [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) - and it contains all children, not only the last one, so the name is confusing as well.

The correct way to do it would be

```
useEffect(() => {
    const children: HTMLCollection | undefined = subCnt.current?.children;
    if (!children?.length) return;

    const lastChild: HTMLElement = children[children.length - 1];
    …
})
```

but you can actually simplify that by simply using [`.lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/lastElementChild) directly:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const lastChild: HTMLElement | undefined = subCnt.current?.lastElementChild;
    if (!lastChild) return;
    …
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But I am unable to access properties like `.offsetLeft` from lastChild. In both of your implementations. It says `Property 'offsetLeft' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)`

Comment: Ah, right, it's [`HTMLElement.offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft)

Comment: Thanks, and `lastElementChild` has type `Element`, It needs type assertion at the end too, It worked when I also used  `subCnt.current?.lastElementChild as HTMLElement`